# If statement returns condition (to input) insted of checking is input value == condition

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am trying to make quiz site and i have problem with checking answers. If user write his answer in input and click "prześlij" button it makes his answer "WAN, MAN, LAN, WLAN, PAN" and it gives him a point. I tryed to change operators to && but it doesn't work. Any ideas? (I copied full code to give you clear view but the probliem is in function check() ).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <script>

        var points = 0;

        function resultt(){



                        document.getElementById("result").style.display = "block";
                        document.getElementById("ocena").innerHTML = points;





        }
        function exit(){
            document.getElementById("result").style.display = "none";
            document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
            location.reload();
        }
        function check(){
                if(document.getElementById("input").value = "WAN, MAN, LAN, WLAN, PAN" || "WAN, MAN, LAN, PAN" || "WAN MAN LAN PAN" ){
                        points++;
                        document.getElementById("submit1").disabled = true;

                }else
                {
                    document.getElementById("submit1").disabled = true;
                }


        }
        function check_button(){
                    if(document.getElementById("true").clicked == true){
                        points++
                        document.getElementById("true").disabled = true;
                        document.getElementById("false").disabled = true;
                    }else if(document.getElementById("false").clicked == true){
                        document.getElementById("true").disabled = true;
                        document.getElementById("false").disabled = true;
                    }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>


        <h1 id="title">Quiz Z WIEDZY O SIECI</h1>


             <h1 id="pytanie1">Wypisz typy sieci od najbardziej rozległej do najmniej rozległej <br> (typy są 4, posługuj się skrutami)</h1>
                <input type="text" id="input" size="50"/>
                <input type="submit" id="submit1"onclick="check()">


            <h1 id="pytanie2">W jakim modelu sieci komputer w ramach danej usługi może być jednocześnie klijentem oraz serwerem?</h1>
                <input type="text" id="input5" size="50"/>
                <input type="submit" id="submit2" onclick="">


            <h1 id="pytanie3">Jaka warstwa w modelu TCP/IP odpowiada za dostarczanie informacji do użądzenia docelowego?</h1>
                <input type="text" id="input2" size="50"/>
                <input type="submit" id="submit3" onclick="">



            <h1 id="pytanie4">Podaj 2 protokoły występujace w warstwie transportu <br> (używaj skrutów)</h1>
                <input type="text" id="input3" size="50"/>
                <input type="submit" id="submit4" onclick="">



            <h1 id="pytanie5">Jaki protokół wykożystany będzie podczas streamingu gry?</h1>
                <button id="true" onclick="check_button()">UDP</button>
                <button id="false" onclick="check_button()">TCP</button>



            <h1 id="pytanie6">Rozwinięcie skrutu DNS to</h1>


                <button id="truee">Domain Name System</button>
                <button id="falsee">Distant Network Service</button>



            <h1 id="pytanie7">W jakiej topologii sieci wszystkie użądzienia są podpięte do jedngo kable?</h1>
                <button id="trueee">Topologia magistrali</button>
                <button id="falseee">Topologia gwiazfy</button>


            <button id="check" onclick="resultt()" href="result">SPRAWDŹ</button><br><br>

            <div id="result">


                <span id="ocena"></span> 





                <button id="SPRÓBUJ_PONOWNIE" onclick="exit()">SPRÓBUJ PONOWNIE</button>



            </div>
                <h1>. </h1><br>
                <h1>. </h1><br>
                <h1>.</h1><br>
                <h1>. </h1><br>
                <h1>. </h1><br>
                <h1>. </h1><br>
                <h1>. </h1><br>
                <h1>.</h1><br>
                <h1>. </h1><br>
                <h1>. </h1><br>
                <h1>. </h1><br>
                <h1>. </h1><br>
                <h1>.</h1><br>
                <h1>. </h1><br>
                <h1>. </h1><br>






</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to make a loop and place your conditional in it, then iterate through the conditional with each potential answer... Right now you are checking to see if the input is = to the entire string of answers, also you need to compare, not assign --> strict `===` or `==`

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
if (document.getElementById("input").value == "WAN, MAN, LAN, WLAN, PAN")
```

and not

```
if (document.getElementById("input").value = "WAN, MAN, LAN, WLAN, PAN")
```

Take care of `=` (assignment) vs `==` (comparison). :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a loop that iterates through the input values the user has input on click of the submit button. Define an array that holds the values of your answers and compare those with the input values the user inputs each time you iterate through the loop.

In my example below, I define an array for your potential answers and then use a `foraEach` loop on the element selectors for the inputs. After we define the `current` value within the `forEach` loop we create a `for` loop to check if the answers are equal to any of the answers in the array. If we get a match, run the code to give a point.

I used the strict comparator so we `trim()` white space and add `toUpperCase()` to make sure there are no spaces in the answer and the input is in uppercase as are the answers in the array we will be comparing the inputs to.

```js
//--> query the id for the button element, will be used for click event
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
//--> get the list of elements that are <input>, i used the class with querySelectorAll
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.inputs');
//--> initiate an array to hold the values of your answers
let answers = ['WAN', 'MAN', 'LAN', 'WLAN', 'PAN'];
//--> this variable will be the current answer we will be comparing to the answers array throuhg each iteration
let answer;
//--> click event wraps around the loops
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  //forEach loop to iterate through the input elements
  inputs.forEach(function(val) {
    //--> hold the current iteration of the input in the answer variable
    answer = val.value.trim().toUpperCase();
    //--> for loop to itarate through the answers array, we use a classic for loop iterator method here
    //--> using the array.length method as a stop
    for (let i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
      //--> now compare the answer with the current iteration of the answers arrays value
      //--> keep in mind the strict comparator is being used here in the conditional "==="
      //--> capitalization will be key to returning true value as well as white space trimming in the input value
      if (answer === answers[i]) {
        //-- now run code for correct answer and iterate a point
        console.log(answer + ' Correct!')
      }
    }
  })

})
```

```html
<input type="text" class="inputs">
<input type="text" class="inputs">
<input type="text" class="inputs">
<input type="text" class="inputs">
<input type="text" class="inputs">
<button id="btn">Submit</button>
```